# How can I remotely install (and uninstall) ClickOnce applications?

Tags: .net, clickonce

I need to deploy multiple ClickOnce applications to 100+ Windows (7) machines.

Is there a "lazy" way to accomplish this without having to leave the comfort of my desk...?

Comment: Don't know ClickOnce enough to be sure it will works, but maybe you can push an new update to the app that will trigger the uninstall on behalf of the user, and maybe also install a *msi* fied package ?

Comment: Uninstalling is definitely possible like this. Not an ideal solution, but it works. But that doesn't get me any closer to pushing new applications...

Comment: Did some more digging. [This question, and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841435/is-it-possible-to-automate-a-clickonce-deployment), proved particularly helpful. Can't believe I missed it in the first place... Seems like ClickOnce just isn't made for this kind of automation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClickOnce are installed on each user account on each computer... If you have any way to remotely connect to EACH user session and install your app, Yes you can!
But all methods I know, are fairly time expensive, if you have 100 machines.

I don't think it possible to push a ClickOnce by a GPO or any other kind of script: for a ClickOnce application, you must click the "install" button!

Here, we split the jobs in three: the Sysadmin, the technician and myself (the developper), and we visit every computers... We have 80 computers. It's take few hours... (Luckily, we did this process only once)

Comment: My question originated from having to go through the process you're describing :-(... I was hoping for something like a GPO solution. If nothing else comes up in the next few days, I'll, regrettably :-), accept your answer.